# Using BOTH error bars and upper/lower limits in python

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, limits, astronomy

Warning: I am very new at python and know very little.

I am trying to graph (x,y) with error bars in both directions. I am able to achieve this, using:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

pyplot.errorbar(x,y,yerr=y_error,xerr=xerror)
```

However, sometimes the error in either x or y is zero. In this case, I want the program to create an upper (x) and lower (y) limit just for those data points. The actual value of the limit doesn't matter; it just needs to show that it is such.

I've found some things suggesting to add 'lolim' and 'uplim' to the pyplot.errorbar, but it's not working. Do I need a for loop or something to add in the lower/upper limits?

Thanks.

Comment: See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2452

Comment: The posted site helps, but it still does not answer my main problem. How do I get limits displayed ONLY when the error is zero? Some data points need error bars, and the others need limits. I have hundreds of data points, so the practice from the website of just listing the points to do limits on in brackets will not work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just use something like `numpy.where` to make the "lims" arrays?

Comment: When I attempted to use numpy.where, it gave me multiple errors. I don't think it applicable to what I need. I'm playing with a new idea, but it's not quite working:    if x_error. == 0:
     uplim = np.zeros(x.shape)
     uplim = True
    else:
     uplim = False, but I need it to work on specific values of the array, not the whole thing. I really have no clue how to get it to plot limits on values with a specific error. Any help there?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest a simple solution like so:

all the non-limits:

```
ind1 = y_error*x_error!=0
pyplot.errorbar(x[ind1],y[ind1],yerr=y_error[ind1],xerr=xerror[ind1],fmt='k+')
```

x-limits:

```
ind2 = x_error==0  
pyplot.errorbar(x[ind2],y[ind2],yerr=y_error[ind2],fmt='k<')
```

y-limits:

```
ind3 = y_error==0  
pyplot.errorbar(x[ind3],y[ind3],xerr=x_error[ind3],fmt='kv')
```

I'll leave it to you to decide what to do with the cases where both x and y are limits.